# PayLoad Directory not getting created

Tags: ios, ipad, ipa, payload

I'm having a project with Non-ARC,now I migrated the application Xcode 6 with SDK 8.1 after succesful migration, when I tried to archive it the *.ipa file got created but if I tried to upload the app via diawi or hokey app the it shows a issue

Say In Diawi it shows
**No professional profile found**

I tried changing it to .zip & extracted the zip there I found out instead of creating **PayLoad directory** it shows me **Applications directory** ,From that I came to know  there is no Payload directory created that is the issue .

Kindly help me in this , Why Payload directory not been created ?

I just to add a script for creating Payload directory but that not worked for me.

Comment: I've enclosed a script , which will create .app file inside the Payload directory & provide a proper ipa file. Here is the script .

Comment: mkdir $CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR/Payload
cp -R $CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR/$PRODUCT_NAME.app $CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR/Payload
cd $CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR
/usr/bin/zip -r $PRODUCT_NAME.ipa Payload
rm -rf Payload
exit 0

Comment: I got the exact issue . I have set Application Requires iPhone Environment which is in plist to YES , the issue fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To correct it, I need to edit the Info.plist file to set:

Application requires iPhone environment = YES